# parsing with expression including a newline in python

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, beautifulsoup

I was trying to parsing some html files, in which I want to extract some value called "Total Cash", but these html come in two different forms:

1. `...Total Cash (mrq):</td> <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">8.71B</td>...`
2. `...Total Cash (mrq):</td> 
   <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">8.71B</td>...`

It is easy to parsing the first one, and the following code gives me the number 8.71B

```
source.split('Total Cash (mrq):</td> <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">')[1].split('</td>')[0]
```

However, I don't know how to parse the second form, in which the value and the string 'Total Cash (mrq)' are in two different lines. Any suggestions? Also, there are about 9000 htmls, and each file contains about 1000 rows of code.

Comment: `source = line1 + line2` and then process as normal?

Comment: you tagged the question with `beautifulsoup` , why not using soup' methods ?

Comment: @ TigerhawkT3: source is a html file which contains about 1100line of data, not just one line of code.

Comment: @ Abdelrahman Elkady, never use it before, hope someone could give me suggestions including possibilities of using beautifulsoup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this as you mentioned `beautifulsoup`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<td>Total Cash (mrq):</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1">8.71B</td>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

td_head = soup.find(text="Total Cash (mrq):").parent
td_desired = td_head.find_next('td')

print td_desired.contents[0]
```

If you need to get all the elements you can try `find_all` , by using something like this :

```
td_heads_content = soup.find_all(text="Total Cash (mrq):")
for elem in td_heads_content:
    td_head = elem.parent
```

Comment: when run this code through all my file (about 9000 HTML files, each file has about 1000 lines of data), the program eat all my memory before I can finish go through the entire dataset, any suggestions?